# create a android soft keyboard with other views attached to it

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to develop a custom keyboard where I can add other views above it. how can I achieve this? what will be the main container layout?
I basically want to add banner ads on top of the keyboard. you can provide be a general example to put any view with keyboard view.

[like this keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNlsz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboards must implement an InputMethodService.  One of the functions on it is onCreateInputView.  That returns the View to display.  This can be any View you want, including q layout with ads.

That said-  nobody will ever use a keyboard with ads on it.  I really don't suggest it.